# Unmarshall xml using Document instead of StreamSource

Tags: java, xml, moxy, unmarshalling

I previously unmarshaled my documents with this Method from "javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller" (i am using Moxy as jaxb provider):

```
<Object> JAXBElement<Object> javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Source source, Class<Object> declaredType) throws JAXBException
```

Now i have to refactor my code to use

```
<?> JAXBElement<?> javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Node node, Class<?> declaredType) throws JAXBException
```

The problem is that i get an unmarshal exception:

```
    Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-25004] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.0.v20120608-r11652): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.XMLMarshalException
Exception Description: An error occurred unmarshalling the document
Internal Exception: org.xml.sax.SAXParseExceptionpublicId: ; systemId: ; lineNumber: 0; columnNumber: 0; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'invoice:request'.]
```

i tried unmarshal with Document and with Document.getDocumentElement(). The data in document is the same as in InputStream. Document is created this way:

```
    protected static Document extractDocument(InputStream sourceData) {
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc;
    try {
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(sourceData));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Problem on reading xml, cause: ", e);
    }
    return doc;
}
```

I need the "intermediate" Document to do the type recognition/ to get the second argument for unmarshal.

so how to use the unmarshal method with Node/Document that the outcome is the same as used with the inputstream?

**Edit for rick**

I am unmarshalling xml data from [here](http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/xmlstandards/xml_4.3/xml_rechnung_xml_4.3/xml_rechnung_generelle_rechnung_xml_4.3) xsds are in [this zip](http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/generalinvoicerequest_430.xsd.zip) and examples are [here](http://www.forum-datenaustausch.ch/xmlstandards_generelle_rechnung_beispiele_anfrage_4.3_20100901.zip).

i wrote a simple test (jaxb provider is moxy, it was also used to generate the binding classes):

```
    @Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    Unmarshaller um;
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
            .newInstance("....generatedClasses.invoice.general430.request");
    um = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

    InputStream xmlIs = SingleTests.class.getResourceAsStream("/430_requests/dentist_ersred_TG_430.xml");

    SchemaFactory sf = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
    Schema schema = sf.newSchema(this.getClass().getResource("/xsd/" + "generalInvoiceRequest_430.xsd"));
    // start
    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document doc;
    try {
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = docBuilder.parse(new InputSource(xmlIs));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception("Problem on recognizing invoice type of given xml, cause: ", e);
    }
    // end
    um.setSchema(schema);
    um.unmarshal(doc, ....generatedClasses.invoice.general430.request.RequestType.class);

}
```

This is not working with the error described above. But as soon as deleted the "start end block" and unmarshall the stream xmlIs directly (not using the Document) the code works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok i asked the same Question [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1043333/) the answer is:

simple add

```
docBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

The following code works for me with a simple test model and gives the same result in all three cases:

```
    JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] { TestObject.class }, null);

    Source source = new StreamSource("src/stack16038604/instance.xml");
    JAXBElement o1 = ctx.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(source, TestObject.class);
    System.out.println(o1.getValue());

    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream inputStream2 = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("stack16038604/instance.xml");
    Document node = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream2);
    JAXBElement o2 = ctx.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(node, TestObject.class);
    System.out.println(o2.getValue());

    DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory2 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    InputStream inputStream3 = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("stack16038604/instance.xml");
    InputSource inputSource = new InputSource(inputStream3);
    Document node2 = builderFactory2.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputSource);
    JAXBElement o3 = ctx.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(node2, TestObject.class);
    System.out.println(o3.getValue());
```

If you provided a systemId in the Source use-case, then you should use the same systemId on the InputSource you create:

```
inputSource.setSystemId(sameIdAsYouUsedForSource);
```

If you are still having problems could you post the XML that you are trying to unmarshal?  Also if your JAXB objects were generated from an XML Schema that could provide useful information as well.

Hope this helps,

Rick

Comment: I edited my question. i tried it (this was also my first try) to use the "Document" directly but it is not working.